# How to add highlight text on my candlechart by MPandroidChart?

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KujDK.png)
I just wanted to add "To show a small square around the highlight crosshair, which shows the data from the Y-axis when I swipe on the chart" in my chart, 
For example, If I use a linechart
Entry data is constructed by the following for loop

```
for (int i = 0; i <= barcount; i ++) {
LinValues.add (new Entry (i, 10000 + 2 * i));
}
///Set LineDataSet
LineDataSet setline = new LineDataSet (LinValues, "AVER");
setline.setAxisDependency (YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);
setline.setColor (Color.GREEN);
setline.setLineWidth (1f);
setline.setDrawCircles (false);
setline.setDrawValues ​​(false);
setline.setHighLightColor (Color.WHITE);
LineData line = new LineData (setline);
Legend l =combchart.getLegend();
l.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
YAxis yLAxis =combchart.getAxisLeft();
yLAxis.setTextSize(22f);
yLAxis.setLabelCount(5,true);
yLAxis.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
YAxis yRAxis = combchart.getAxisRight();
yRAxis.setEnabled(false);
Linechat.setData (line);
```

How can I to add the "ith value" from "LinValues" ​​next to the ith crosshair and when I slide to the "nth data point" , the value near the crosshair will change value to"nth value"from"LinValues?
Can you help me?????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok this can be done by using marker view for that follow instructions below:

First of all add java class CustomMarkerView in your project and write below code in it.

```
package maniac.professionalchartsfree.Utilities;

import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.github.mikephil.charting.components.MarkerView;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.Entry;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.highlight.Highlight;

import maniac.professionalchartsfree.R;

/**
 * Created by saad.rafique on 1/5/2018.
*/

public class CustomMarkerView extends MarkerView
{
private TextView tvContent;

public CustomMarkerView(Context context, int layoutResource, int valueSize, int valueColor)
{
    super(context, layoutResource);
    // this markerview only displays a textview
    tvContent = findViewById(R.id.tvContent);
    tvContent.setTextSize(valueSize);
    tvContent.setTextColor(valueColor);
}

// callbacks everytime the MarkerView is redrawn, can be used to update the
// content (user-interface)

@Override
public void refreshContent(Entry e, Highlight highlight)
{
    tvContent.setText("x: " + e.getX() + "\n" +"y: " + e.getY()); // set the entry-value as the display text
}

}
```

After that create a custom_marker.xml file in your layout folder and write following code in it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="75dp"
android:layout_height="75dp"
android:background="@drawable/markers_bg"
>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvContent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

</LinearLayout>
```

After that add method in your activity where your are creating chart:

```
public CustomMarkerView markerView(Context context)
{
    CustomMarkerView mv = new CustomMarkerView(context, R.layout.custom_marker, 16, Color.WHITE);
    mv.setOffset(- mv.getWidth() / 2, -mv.getHeight()-25);
    return mv;
}
```

After that add following lines:

```
    lineChart.setDrawMarkers(true);
    lineChart.setMarker(markerView(context));
```

Now run your project and when you click point of your line chart you will get what you want.

Comment: Do let me know for further assistance. Happy coding bro!